# How to solve the projectile problem with numerical method in matlab

Tags: numerical-methods

i wanna ask how to solve the projectile problem using matlab? could you give me the source code in matlab? 
the equations is x"=-(1+0.1*x)^2 , with x(0)=0, x'(0)=1.
thanks before.

Comment: Which method you want to implement for solution? Euler? Runge-Kutta?